# Domain names and redirecting with proper SEO using IIS 7.5, ASP.Net v4.0 and MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, seo, dns, iis-7.5, asp.net-4.0

Let's say I have several sites I want to create - all with separate domain names.  Each of these sites uses the same back-end, and the configured all from the same back-end.

As such, I was wondering if I could do the following:

In each of the sites' DNS, point them all to the same site.

So for example:

- site1.com, site2.com, site3.com ---> mymainbackend.com

Then at mymainbackend.com, I would read the incoming Url, and serve up the appropriate content based on that incoming URL.

One issue with this is that all the sites would reside on the same app pool, but a work-around would be to have batched pools.

The architecture for this is IIS 7.5, MVC3, ASP.Net 4.0.

Are there any SEO got'cha's with this type of scenario?  Are there better solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run 4 different domains from the same hosting using the routing module to decide what content to serve.

SEO wise there should be no specific issues.

It would be the same as hosting multiple websites on the same server and the potential issues that may raise.

Comment: Could you please give me some more details about how you set that up?

Comment: Mine is very custom. You need to learn about the routing module and use one of the many ways you can interact with it. It intercepts requests and can decide how they get handled. I created an IRouteHandler and wrote my own Route class to manage routing based on the host/domain